# How can Feign send nested object properties as HTTP GET query parameters using dot notation?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-rest, spring-cloud-feign, openfeign

I have a Spring app 1 that calls another Spring app 2. It does this via REST using Feign:

```
interface MyFeignClient{
    @GetMapping("/car/search")
   List<Car> findCars(
            @SpringQueryMap Car searchCar);
}
```

In both apps, I have the following:

```
class Car {
   Model model;
}
class Model{
  String name;
}
```

In Spring app 1, feign builds query param as model=Model(name=Camry). So, the URL is http://app2-service/car/search?model=Model(name=Camry)

But in app2, my (standard) Spring's @RestController can only map query param into a `Car` when using dot notation like model.name=Camry.

```
@GetMapping("/car/search")
public List<Car> findCars(
        Car searchCar) {
```

How can I have Feign send query params using the standard Spring dot notation (e.g., model.name)?